# How can I save a SQL query as a SQL file in pgAdmin?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have tried to save it but I cannot put a name to the file and I cannot click on the "Save Button".
It is a very simple question, but I didn't find an answer.

[image: pgAdmin screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to type the filename after the folder path that appears in the top bar. Then the 'Create' button will be enabled.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it looks after selecting a file to store in
[image: This is how it looks after selecting a file to store in]

now just type anything after the last  \  in the top bar
[image: now just type anything after the last \ in the top bar]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).